# Why won't Windows 8.1 64 bit (MacBook Air) recognize all 1GB video memory?

Tags: bootcamp, graphics, windows

My 2011 MacBook Air has 8GB of RAM and Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB

My Windows 8.1 partition (64 bit) doesn't recognize more than 128MB of video memory, causing graphics oriented programs to crash.

Is there some sort of driver update or anything I can do to fix this?

Windows is always kept updated.

Comment: What other software are you using to get Windows on the Mac? Boot Camp version? Emulation or virtualization software and version? Also - be specific on driver versions - "always updated" means nothing - especially tomorrow when someone could let you know the version you have is out dated or if you need to go back to an older version.

Comment: I said WINDOWS is always updated.  Yes it does mean something... every update is installed as it is made available. duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MacBook Air has [integrated graphics](http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2012/01/integrated-vs-dedicated-a-difference-in-graphics/) so the system memory (total RAM) is shared between the OS (traditional RAM) and integrated graphics (stuff that handles drawing pictures on the CPU, that needs some RAM to itself as well).

OS X dynamically partitions that amount of VRAM versus system RAM at any given time (per [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349)). Windows likely doesn't have this function built-in, but it looks like there are a few [ways to control it](http://www.pvladov.com/2013/10/increase-intel-hd-graphics-dedicated-video-memory.html).

Comment: Thanks! There doesn't seem to be an easy way around this so I'll leave it be.